# How to set the screen brightness to dim

Tags: android, screen, brightness, screen-brightness

at present the following code is setting the screen brightness level to 0 but it is not dimming the screen.can somebody help me out.the android version is 4.0.
thanks in advance.

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(
 context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 0);
```

Comment: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-change-screen-brightness-programmatically/

Comment: @Nirav thanku for the info but even this code is not working out

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 20);

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 0.2f; // 100 / 100.0f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

startActivity(new Intent(this,RefreshScreen.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
public static void wakeDevice(Context context) {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            (PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "");

    //calling this will Dim the screen
    wakeLock.acquire();

    //if  you want to release the dim state
    //wakeLock.release();
}
```

Comment: thanku for the info but still even this one is not working out.